# Using bytefield as parameter to self-defined macro raises error

Tags: tables, macros, bytefield

I defined a simple LaTeX macro `\bansen` which takes a single argument:

```
\newcommand{\bansen}[1]{#1}
```

Unfortunately, I noticed that I can not use a `bytefield` environment as a parameter for this macro as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\newcommand{\bansen}[1]{#1}    \usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}
\bansen{
    \begin{bytefield}{16}
        \wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field}\\
        \bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits}
    \end{bytefield}
}
\end{document}
```

because that would create an error at the macro's closing bracket `}`:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.11 }
```

which was apparently introduced by the `&` character -- replacing that line by

```
        \bitbox{8}{8 bits} % & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits}
```

lets the error vanish together with the second column of that line.

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong and how to fix this?

Motivation: My real macro `\bansen` contains several other typesetting commands and several more parameters. The LaTeX code which uses that macro is computer-generated which allows me to keep content (generator) and form (LaTeX style) separated, so I am not too fond of the idea to not use a macro.

Comment: Did you try putting the argument in a group?  ie `\newcommand{\bansen}[1]{{#1}}` or possibly using a `makebox` around the argument?

Comment: Ignore that previous comment, but just get rid of the `&` between the two bitboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For its internal purposes, `bytefield` changes the category code of `&` upon starting the environment. This change cannot affect the argument already absorbed by `\bansen`, so you have to do the category change beforehand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\newcommand{\bansen}{%
  \begingroup\catcode`&=10
  \banseninternal}
\newcommand{\banseninternal}[1]{%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}{16}
\wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field}\\
\bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits}
\end{bytefield}

\bigskip

\bansen{%
  \begin{bytefield}{16}
  \wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field}\\
  \bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits}
  \end{bytefield}%
}

\end{document}
```

The supplementary formatting instruction will go in `\banseninternal` instead of `\bansen`.

[image]

Comment: As a side effect, this would mean that a `tabular` environment can never be used as a parameter for `\bansen` since the `&` character was temporarily reclassified as whitespace. I can circumvent that and not use tabulars (by modifying the generator), but is there a solution to that problem? I thought about redeclaring environments but I do not see if this could help.

Comment: @Twonky No, you can't use `&` in the argument to `\bansen`, but you can do `\let\AMP=&` and use `\AMP` for `&`. A character can't have two category codes at the same time.