# bytefield inside tabular

Tags: tables, bytefield

I wonder why it is not easily possible to put a bytefield enviroment into a tabular. This MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{bytefield}{2}
         \bitheader{0-1} \\ \bitbox{1}{0} \bitbox{1}{2}
    \end{bytefield}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

produces this pdflatex error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> \unskip \hfil }
                          \hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate 
l.5 \begin{bytefield}{2}
```

Because of the valid answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247244/using-bytefield-as-parameter-to-self-defined-macro-raises-error), I fear that it's again some key codes which are mangled by bytefield. But I lack the ability to find the solution.

**Edit (addendum):**

While enclosing the bytefield in braces helps with the simple example, I noticed that trouble comes with more complicated use. Since the alignmend of the bytefield is a bit weird, I feel forced into using `\raisebox` so that the bytefield numbers no longer overlap with the previous line.

Freakingly, this works only with the first line. Consider this advanced example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}\hline
    \raisebox{-1ex}[5ex][1.5ex]{
        {\begin{bytefield}[endianness=big,bitwidth=5em]{1}
        \bitheader{0} \\ \bitbox{1}{uint8}
        \end{bytefield}}}
    \\ \hline
    \raisebox{-1ex}{
        {\begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=5em]{2}
        \bitheader{0,1} \\ \bitbox{1}{MSB} & \bitbox{1}{LSB}
        \end{bytefield}}}
\end{tabular}
```

which produces the error

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 
l.13    \end{bytefield}}}
```

If the second `\raisebox` is removed, the first line's layout is correct, the second is not:
[image]

Comment: I added a fix also for your addendum, though it was ***completely*** unrelated. Please, avoid modifying questions so as to invalidate existing answers. And ensure the example code is compilable: the one you added doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to brace the `bytefield` environment:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  {\begin{bytefield}{2}
   \bitheader{0-1} \\ \bitbox{1}{0} \bitbox{1}{2}
   \end{bytefield}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addendum

There is no misalignment if you properly protect the end-of-line; if you have `bytefield` inside `\raisebox`, there's no need of the additional braces, already provided by `\raisebox` (implicitly), but they do no harm.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}\hline
    \raisebox{-1ex}[5ex][1.5ex]{% <---- HERE
        \begin{bytefield}[endianness=big,bitwidth=5em]{1}
        \bitheader{0} \\ \bitbox{1}{uint8}
        \end{bytefield}}
    \\ \hline
    \raisebox{-1ex}[5ex][1.5ex]{% <---- HERE
        \begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=5em]{2}
        \bitheader{0,1} \\ \bitbox{1}{MSB} \bitbox{1}{LSB}
        \end{bytefield}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know this violates the rules for comments, but egreg, you are awesome!

Comment: @Twonky An esteemed member of the community maintains that my only ability with TeX is spotting missing `%`'s. Maybe he's right. `;-)`